# Does anyone have recommendations for a good (and lightweight!) PHP mailer library?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Pretty much as the title says.

I'm currently using the SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org), but I'm just wondering how it stacks up to the other libraries out there.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about libraries like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [HTMLMimeMail](http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html) *(I've used this one for a couple of projects in the past ; never had any problem with it)* or the like, but I think, for a project of my own, I'd have a look at [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)

Why ? I see at least two reasons :

- Zend Framework's components are well written, well tested
- There are maintenance releases of the Framework quite often (about once a month), which is good to know ; the project is alive
- It might be the occasion to begin using other components as well **;-)**

And for a couple of drawbacks :

- You might have to extract that component (and the components it rely on) from the Framework if you don't want to include it as a whole **:-(**
- Officialy, you'll need PHP >= 5.2.4 *(not sure about the .4)* ; some components work with PHP 5.1.x, but it's not officialy supported

Comment: I agree. Those are all good libraries but I've found Zend_Mail to be the best as well. Very flexible, good coding standards and a well supported.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) Not sure how it stacks up, but it's definitely a contender..

Edit: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer) post to see how the two stack up

Comment: I started to use it 3 years ago, works perfectly even with 3000+ users mailing lists (sending a simple html page with no attachments).

Works pretty nice with google apps (connecting by smtp to gmail).

p.s: dont use gmail to send maling list!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone using PHPMailer, there is an exploit which makes it possible to read any file on the server. Check sourceforge documentation for PHPMailer to see more information.

Comment: can you provide a link to the direct page? cant find it on sourceforge.. please

Answer (score -2):

Another vote for PHPMailer here, been using it for years and haven't any problems.

Funnily enough I was looking at trying out SwiftMailer a few months back but saw some concerns about performance of the latest version on the forums which kind of put me off...