# php mail() function doesn't send mails

Tags: php, email

I configure my php.ini and sendmail.ini,i wrote a simple code to send mail but i don't receive anything on my mail adresse.

```
<?php 
mail('hmidi_slim@hotmail.fr','test message','1 2 test');
?>
```

php.ini:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path ="C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe"
```

sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
default_domain=gmail.com
auth_username=powerfulcar12@gmail.com
auth_password=password
force_sender=powerfulcar12@gmail.com
```

Comment: Did sendmail work for you?

Comment: Check your ([error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)) logs and/or Spam box.

Comment: Does your server require an authenticated email address to prevent spam? Check with your hosting provider.

Comment: Not all servers have a public SMTP, some require an authenticated user.

Comment: Did you bother checking the return value of the mail() call? If that returns true, then your problem is somwhere farther down the line at the mail server level.

Comment: Try `SMTP Port: 465` - *"If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL) and port 587 (with TLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL)."* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use sendmail PHP function directly. It does not follow any RFC mailing specifications, it's just very simple PHP function. It used to be sufficient years ago before many RFCs came out :-)

Use some **PHP mailing library** that will create correct mail headers + body and send email for you (via SMTP, POP3 or sendmail). I would recommend either PHPMailer or SwiftMailer - see [this thread on  PHP mailing software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220560/does-anyone-have-recommendations-for-a-good-and-lightweight-php-mailer-librar/1220676#1220676).

You may also be interested in testing emails locally without sending them out of your network - see [here how to  setup environment](http://www.synet.sk/php/en/155-testing-php-mail-on-localhost-with-fake-smtp-server-hMailServer-and-outlook).

Comment: Can you name any specification or functionality, `mail()` is not capable of? It's working perfect as is. Can put headers into, can prepare multipart, can deliver to SMTP and authenticate. What else do you need?

Comment: P.S this is not an answer to the question

Comment: Using external library MAY potentially fix the issue regarded in this question e.g. by composing correct email body or correctly handling SMTP communication. It is not possible to answer directly since no exact error message or error log was provided. Another benefit of using such a library is efficiency - e.g. embedding inline images would be tremendous job with pure sendmail function - but hey - why reinvent the wheel ? :-)