# PHP - Plain text email

Tags: php, email, plaintext

How to turn this into a plain text email?

```
 $bound_text=md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$bound_text\"\r\n";

    $message="--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"      
                ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"  
                ."<html><head></head><body>"
                ."<div style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 1.3em; color: #000000;width: 100%;text-align: left;\">$text_message</div></body></html>\r\n\r\n"  
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"  
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$attachment\"\r\n\r\n"
     .chunk_split($file)
            ."\r\n\r\n"
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text--\r\n\r\n";

    }
```

Is it just removing the HTML part and changing **text/html** into **text/plain**?

Comment: Probably. But have you considered using [PHPMailer or Swiftmailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer) for not having to micromanage things like that?

Comment: For now I need to go with the posted code but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are sure that `$text_message` contains no HTML markup itself, then you're probably safe. Otherwise you may need to do some tidying up of that variable (e.g. `'<br />'` -> `"\n"`, strip_tags)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removing the HTML should do the trick but you'll probably want to change the content-type to text/plain as well:

```
."Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
```

(I would have let a comment suffice but I can't post comments yet :))