# PHP Form only emails 1 value

Tags: php, html, forms, web, html-email

When I submit my html form I am only getting the $name value in my email. Also when I click submit instead of redirecting to my thank you html page the content of the thank you page appears underneath the form. Any ideas why? Here is my code...

HTML:

```
<section class="container content">

<div class="row">
<div class="center title col-sm-12">
<h2>Short Application Form</h2>
</div>
</div> 

<h2>Personal Information</h2>
<form method="post" action="appemail.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="row">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">First Name</label>
<span><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<span><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<span><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></span>
</div>

<!--<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="email">Referral Name</label>
<span><input type="email" name="email" id="email"/></span>
</div>-->

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="email">Home/Cell Phone</label>
<span><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label>Martial Satus</label>
<select name="martial">
    <option>Married</option>
    <option>Unmaried</option>
    <option>Seperated</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label>Are you a Canadian Permanent Resident</label>
<select name="resident">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="email">Date of Birth</label>
<span><input type="text" name="birth"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="email">Number of Dependents</label>
<span><input type="text" name="dependents"/></span>
</div>

<div class="center title col-sm-12">
 <h2 style="text-align:left">Current Address</h2>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Street Address</label>
<span><input type="text" name="adress"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">City</label>
<span><input type="text" name="city"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Province</label>
<span><input type="text" name="province"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Postal Code</label>
<span><input type="text" name="postal"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Years at this Address</label>
<span><input type="text" name="years"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label>Rent or Own</label>
<select name="rent">
    <option>Own</option>
    <option>Rent</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="center title col-sm-12">
 <h2 style="text-align:left">Subject Property</h2>
 </div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label>Property Usage</label>
<select name="property">
    <option>Primary Residence</option>
    <option>Second Home</option>
     <option>Investment</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Loan Amount $ </label>
<span><input type="text" name="loan"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Purchase Price $</label>
<span><input type="text" name="price"/></span>
</div>

<div class="center title col-sm-12">
 <h2 style="text-align:left">Monthly Income</h2>
 </div>

 <div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Yearly Income $ </label>
<span><input type="text" name="yearly"/></span>
</div>
<div class="form-field col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Other Sources of Income (combined) $</label>
<span><input type="text" name="other"/></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field col-sm-12">
<label for="message">Comments</label>
<span><textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></span>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-click center col-sm-12">
<span><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send it"/></span>
</div>
<div id="alert" class="col-sm-12"></div>
</form>
</section>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$martial = $_POST['martial'];
$resident = $_POST['resident'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$dependents = $_POST['dependents'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];
$years = $_POST['years'];
$rent = $_POST['rent'];
$property = $_POST['property'];
$loan = $_POST['loan'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$other = $_POST['other'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = $visitor_email;
$email_subject = "Application Loan";

$email_body = "You have received a new message from $name\n\n".
    "Here is the Application: \n\n".
    "Phone: $phone\n\n".
    "Martial Status: $martial\n\n".
    "Resident: $resident\n\n".
    "Birth: $birth\n\n".
    "Dependents: $dependents\n\n".
    "Address: $address\n\n".
    "City: $city\n\n".
    "Province: $province\n\n".
    "Postal: $postal\n\n".
    "Years at this Address: $years\n\n".
    "Rent or Own: $rent\n\n".
    "Property: $property\n\n".
    "Loan: $loan\n\n".
    "Price: $price\n\n".
    "Other: $other\n\n".
    "Message: $message\n\n";

$to = "email@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $visitor_email \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location:thank-you.html');
// Function to validate against any email injection attempts

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)','(\r+)','(\t+)','(%0A+)','(%0D+)','(%08+)','(%09+)' );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";

  if(preg_match($inject,$str)){return true;}
  else{return false;}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: martial -> marital :)

Comment: You really should take care about character encoding / escaping. Otherwise your email might get altered and modified by forwarding servers.

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation doesn't work because of the newline.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code and use `<br>` except `\n` & when submit form check data using isset function, add a hidden field for doing it.

Comment: How would the syntax look with <br> ? thanks will add isset functions.

@Patricia

Answer (score 0):

I've copied over your code and it runs fine, except you have a typo with $address.
Sometimes you use address (which is the correct), and sometimes adress.

The email I received:

```
You have received a new message from First Name
Here is the Application:
Phone: 0000000
Martial Status: Married
Resident: Yes
Birth: 2014-10-19
Dependents: 42
Address: Street Address
City: City
Province: Province
Postal: Postal Code
Years at this Address: 42
Rent or Own: Own
Property: Primary Residence
Loan: 42
Price: 42
Other: 42
Message: Comments
```

The new display of lines will work with most email clients because there are no html tags, so it will be displayed as plain text. [Setting the appropriate header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095152/php-plain-text-email) also helps.

Otherwise, what is your back-end?
OS, host, PHP versions?

Comment: I have tried changing the header but I still only get the name value. Also I noticed even if I change it to only send 1 variable the only one that works is $name... I will try to get the host information.

"You have received a new message from myname
Here is the Application:
Phone:
Martial Status:
Resident:
Birth:
Dependents:
Address:
City:
Province:
Postal:
Years at this Address:
Rent or Own:
Property:
Loan:
Price:
Other:
Message:"

Comment: Setting the header at the receiving php script will not affect the POST data it got as input. Anyhow, that's unlikely the problem.
Since the code you provided more-or-less works (martial,address), there's something fishy going around with your environment.
Do you use any framework (cake,symfony,fuel,etc...)? What versions does `phpinfo();` show?