# Sending email with PHP mail()

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

I'm trying to send automated emails with mail(). It sends some emails but not all, around 50%.
To test I'm using the same email address for all emails, and still only some get delivered.

I'm using localhost XAMPP.

Here's the code:

```
if ($_POST['sendEmail'] == "SEND Email") {

    ob_start();

    $buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096);
    $buffer. = "\r\n some HTML \r\n";

    set_time_limit(0);
    $noEmails = $last - $first + 1;
    echo "Emails sent (of $noEmails):";
    for ($index = $first; $index <= $last; $index++) {
        $to = $email["$index"];
        $subject = "Hey {$firstName["
        $index "]}!";
        $message = "$emailMessage";
        $headers = 'From: my_account@gmail.com'."\r\n".'Reply-To: my_account@gmail.com'."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
        sleep(1);
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo $buffer.$index;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}​
```

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Use [phpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) and SMTP instead.

Comment: What shows up in your mail server's logs?

Comment: in the error.log it shows messages like this one: "12/04/12 11:01:08 : Socket Error # 10060<EOL>Connection timed out."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **sending bulk emails** you can **set a cron job** which may run after 5 or 10 minutes that will send only a small quantity of emails at a time. Create a reference in a table that so you can have record of which addresses have been emailed. The whole bulk will be divided into **little chunks** and as it will be running in background it will not put a huge load on your **SMTP server**. You should use **[PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)** or **[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) libraries**.

You can have a look at this question to select which php mailing library is best:

**[PhpMailer vs. Swiftmailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer)**

Hope this helps.