# Send mail with plaintext alternative using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have the following php code for sending email with phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SetFrom($from, $sender_name);
$mail->Subject      = $subject;
$mail->AddAddress($to, "test");
$mail->Body = $body; //$body is an html content
$mail->Send();
```

This will send an email.I need to send plain text alternative with this,for an email client does not have HTML support.

Is possible?
Is possible to do with php `mail()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer has a property `AltBody`, so you could add some plain text like this:

```
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);
```

See the [documentation](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=properties).

Comment: It is a bit more difficult. You need to construct a MIME text as the body with multipart borders. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10267876/578588) on Stack Overflow.