# PHP mail(); Send e-mail as plain text AND a HTML

Tags: php, html, email, boundary

I've the following **PHP** code for sending e-mails with **PHP mail() as HTML**:

```
<?php
    $to = "test@example.com";

    $subject = "This is the subject";

    $headers = "From: Me<test@exapmle.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: test@exapmle.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

    $message = "This is my <b>message</b>!";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

But I want to support plain text and HTML. HTML for things like bold font and plain text to show `This is my message!` in non-html supporting email clients instead of `This is my <b>message</b>!`.

How can I do this?

I read about boundary. Is that what I'm looking for? But if so, how to use it? I don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, boundary is part of what you need.

You can see a full example and explanation of how to do what you're looking to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267840/sending-an-email-with-php-plain-text-and-html.

Comment: @BenShoval I already found this, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @David: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: why not just use phpmailer or swiftmailer?

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest you to use existing library like PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which could do everything you need and even more.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = '<b>Html body</b> here.';
$mail->AltBody = 'Normal text here.';
```

Comment: I don't like libraries.

Comment: I totally agree with no libraries  under no circumstance depend on anything or anybody