# PHP mail script, email not being sent

Tags: email, php

I'm trying to send mail through a simple PHP mail script. I've check the code many times, the page is going to the "Thankyou_page" as if the mail should have been sent, yet I have not received an email yet. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "email@mail.com";
$subject = "Contact Us";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)){
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( $webmaster_email, $subject,
  $comments, "From: " . $email_address);
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you print out the email address to ensure the address is correct?  also the mail function returns true if it is successful and false otherwise.  You should either print it or use if(mail(...)) header... else header(...error_page)

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? Could the mail be flagged as spam?

Comment: Your email headers could be wrong/malformed. In that case, the recipient mail-server rejects your mail, and you wouldn't receive it even if the mail function successfully sent it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use a well written library like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer. Sending emails with the `mail` function without having quite a good command of PHP is a killer.

[PhpMailer vs. SwiftMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified an smtp host in your php.ini file? If so is it correct?

Also, disable the header and print the output of the mail function to see if it is suceeding. It would also be a good idea to enable error reporting in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

is `email@mail.com` a valid email?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: this could be the answer, if the author finds the check useful.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question however. An answer should be formatted as fact- if you want to get some initial conditionals out of the way, use a comment. A useful tip is better left as a comment (or an edit on another answer)