# Swiftmailer Error: Recipient Rejected

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to get Swiftmailer to work but keep getting "recipient rejected" messages.
What causes the "recipient rejected" response?  Is this a response from the gmail server (gmail sensing this is SPAM)?  Is there a way to overcome this?  Otherwise, I will abandon Swiftmailer and try [PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303783/phpmailer-vs-swiftmailer).  I've had success with PEAR packages in the past but got tired of  the configuration and was going to try Swiftmailer first...it shouldn't be this difficult right?

> **My Configuration:**
>   - PHP 5.5.6
>   - Swiftmailer 5.0.3 (with Logger Plugin)
>   - Hosting by GoDaddy *(yeah...I know)*
>
> **Goal:**  Use Swiftmailer to send SMTP message from **admin@mydomain.org** to **legit@gmail.com**
>   
>  *(obviously the email addresses are placeholders for actual addresses)*

Here is the PHP code:  (same as example in Swiftmailer [documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html))

```
<?php 
    require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mydomain.org', 25)
      ->setUsername('admin@mydomain.org')
      ->setPassword('mypassword')
      ;

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);


    $logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
    $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('admin@mydomain.org' => 'admin'))
      ->setTo(array('legit@gmail.com' => 'recipient'))
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
      ;

    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    echo $logger->dump();
?>
```

Here is the relevant logger info:

```
    ...
    ++ Swift_SmtpTransport started
    ...
    >> RCPT TO: <legit@gmail.com>
    << 550 5.1.1 <legit@gmail.com> recipient rejected
    !! Expected response code 250/251/252 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.1 <legit@gmail.com> recipient rejected "
    >> RSET
    << 250 2.0.0 OK
    ++ Stopping Swift_SmtpTransport
    >> QUIT
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a "real" answer, but too long for the comment box:

> Is this a response from the gmail server

Yes.

`recipient rejected` means that, somehow, the recipient (that is, the address you're sending mail to, legit@gmail.com`) is "rejected".

This can have a number of causes

- Email address doesn't exist (anymore) (quite probable)
- User mailbox is full (quite probable)
- The account is blocked by gmail (quite probable)
- the user set a filter to explicitly reject emails from you (not sure if this can be done using gmail, but it's technical possible).
- Your message is considered spam (unlikely, you would probably get a different message)
- ... many others...

It's somewhat unfortunate that gmail doesn't provide more info as to the cause.  I can't find any documentation on gmail's error codes (550 is a generic *"it failed"* code), and usually these sort of messages are more verbose ...

What you could try:

- Make *very* sure the email exists and is valid. Use a different gmail address (ie. one accessible by you) to be sure.
- Check if you're blacklisted, for example using: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
- Try sending mail from `smtp.mydomain.org`, for example with the commandline `mail` utility (if it's a UNIX box), if this doesn't work, you know the problem is at the mail server, if it does work, you know the problem is at Swift mailer.

Comment: just to add to the blacklist possibility: gmail only uses the spamhaus blacklist, unless that has changed recently. any other listings should not impact your ability to deliver. but yeah, speaking from first hand this is not a blacklisting issue - they issue a code specific for that event (5.7.1). i upvoted your answer though, everything said here is spot on.

Comment: The gmail account I'm sending to is my own gmail account so I know that it exists, is not full, is not blocked, and has no filter.  This leads me to think gmail considers the email spam.  This seems odd though because I used the most basic Swiftmailer example and it was blocked by one of the most popular email services?  This doesn't bode well for Swiftmailer if this is the case.

Comment: Follow-up:  I can send mail using the mail utility.  I suspect the problem is with Swiftmailer.  This seems easy for others to duplicate/validate with their own gmail addresses.  If gmail is blocking, this should be a more commonly reported problem.  I suspect it is something else with my Swiftmailer settings?

Comment: Checked the domain against the blacklist website noted by @Carpetsmoker:  Listed 0 times

Comment: @Sparebrain I'm not so certain it's Swift mailer's fault, but trying PHPMailer couldn't hurt & shouldn't be too much effort... It also appears you snipped some output from the log? It might be helpful if you could post the full log.